# ¿Cuales son los recursos que se liberan al utilizar Dispose()?

Tags: c#

He estado leyendo este [blog](https://geeks.ms/jlao/2011/11/29/uso-de-idisposable/) en donde explican el uso de la instrucción using(), pero mencionan que se liberan unos recursos, siempre he escuchado y leído que se tienen que liberar unos recursos o sino corre el riesgo de NO liberarse. Espero que me puedan seguir ayudando ¿Qué tan grave es que NO se liberen estos recursos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resumen, hay dos tipos de recursos: administrados y no administrados.

**Administrados:** Son los recursos usados por objetos que pertenecen a  .NET y de los cuales el recolector de basura (GC) tiene un registro (por eso administrados) y cada cierto tiempo limpia la memoria que se usó para crear esos objetos.

**No administrados**: Son recursos que fueron creados por programas externos a .NET y por lo tanto el recolector de basura no tiene registro de ellos y no puede limpiar la memoria. Ejemplo de esos son los recursos que se usan cuando se hacen llamadas al sistema para leer un archivo, conectarse a una base de datos etc.

La gravedad es que si esos recursos se usan de forma intensiva la memoria se irá agotando poco a poco hasta provocar una falla en el sistema, se conoce como fuga de memoria.

[documentación Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged)

Comment: Ahora veo lo peligroso que es al no usar el dispose()